# How to find out the list of companies of a fund?

Tags: etf, ethical-investing

It is possible to find the full list of companies for a fund, like [UBS ETF (LU) MSCI World Socially Responsible UCITS ETF (USD) A-dis](https://www.justetf.com/etf-profile.html?isin=LU0629459743)?

In particular, I would like to know if it contains Monsanto, Bayer, Nestle or companies with industrial livestock farming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.finanzen.net/etf/ubs-etf_msci_world_socially_responsible_ucits_etf_a) you find some PDFs linked to that fund. Among these is the yearly report ("Jahresbericht"), where on page 274 to 281 you find the list of components.

It contains Coca Cola and McDonalds, but none of these you mentioned (as far as I could see at first glance). But better check for yourself.

Comment: Are the pagenumbers from `Jahresbericht/Rechenschaftsbericht (31.12.2018)` ? It seems to me that the pages starting from 169 and I spottet Nestle India on page 170 at the bottom I think.

Comment: This report refers to all funds from UBS (or, at least, a whole bunch of them). On one of the first pages, you find the table of contents where the list of each funds' components is listed. On the top of each page, you find the name of the fund it refers to. E. g. on page 270 (not 170!), it says "MSCI Emerging Markets Socially Responsible UCITS ETF" in the title. While that is a different fund, that fact definitely makes me wonder how they define "Socially Responsible".